# Arrayformula/Spill Formula to sequence numbers, restarting after encountering blanks?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365

I am trying to essentially autonumber subtasks in a tasklist such that the subtasks are numbered under the main task's heading. I have a helper column right now where tasks are labeled primary or secondary to assist with formulas.

[image: Desired Result]

I've found solutions that solve this problem with a pulldown formula that references the previous formula in the row:

```
=IF(LEN(B3)>0,"",IF(C2="",1,C2+1))
```

but I was hoping I could get an arrayformula to make it more idiot proof. I tried this, based off the aboive example formula and got a circular reference:

```
=BYROW(A3:A16,LAMBDA(x,IF(LEN(x)>0,"",IF(LEN(OFFSET(x,-1,))>0,1,OFFSET(x,-1,)+1))))
```

Is there a way to achieve the result programmatically? So far, I cant think of a solution that doesnt reference itself.

I'd greatly prefer a formula based solution but interested in VBA as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `SCAN()` function:

[image]

---

```
=SCAN("",A3:A15,LAMBDA(α,δ,IF(δ="",α+1,0)))
```

---

The above formula shows `zeros` which is hidden using custom formatting - `0;;` however if one needs to completely use to formula to suppress the zeros then can use the following as well:

```
=LET(φ, SCAN("",A3:A16,LAMBDA(α,δ,IF(δ="",α+1,0))), IF(φ=0,"",φ))
```

---

Or, use as mentioned by **[VBasic2008](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9814069/vbasic2008)** Sir, it doesn't require the additional `LET()` function or doesn't require custom formatting,

```
=SCAN("",A3:A16,LAMBDA(α,δ,IF(δ="",N(α)+1,"")))
```

---

Comment: This is excellent. My only question is, how do you supress the zeroes? In your original image there were zeroes instead of blanks inbetween cells, like this new picture here.

Comment: Yes its hidden by using custom formatting. Select the range. Press `CTRL+1`, Custom and type `0;;` -->ok. But if you want to use a formula then : `=LET(φ, SCAN("",A3:A16,LAMBDA(α,δ,IF(δ="",α+1,0))), IF(φ=0,"",φ))`

Comment: How about `=SCAN("",A3:A15,LAMBDA(α,δ,IF(δ="",N(α)+1,"")))`?

Comment: @VBasic2008 Sir, works let me update it. Thanks. Completely forgotten abt `N()` here